# ionic serve building ionic2 project as ionic1 project

Tags: ionic2, ionic-cli

I have **Ionic2** project it run and built ok with **ionic serve**.
but after some time it build project as it is in **Ionic1** project

this output

```
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit
enter code here
```

and this ionic config

```
{
  "name": "my-side-menu",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true, 
  "typescript": true
}
```

Comment: it is run ok after restart pc

Comment: Facing Same Problem

Comment: @GautamSahu upvote the question